# Next.js jsx style class not applied to a dynamic content

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-jsx

I am a beginner in Next.js and react and I am trying to use `<style jsx>` for styling my page.
It works in most cases but when I generate the content on the fly the className styles are not applied.
It is hard to explain by words because I am not familiar yet with the terminology, therefore I will try to explain by example (tried to make it as simple as possible).
Here is my page content:

```js
import React from 'react';
    
const articles = ["dogs", "cats", "mice"]
    
function JsxDc() {
    const articleJsx = articles.map((art, idx) => (
        <li className="articleItem" key={idx}>{art} </li>
    ));
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="pageCont">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <ul>
                    {articleJsx}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <style jsx>{`
                .pageCont {
                    color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
                }
                .articleItem{
                    color: red;
                }
            `}</style>
        </>
    )
}
    
export default JsxDc;
```

and here is how I see it in the browser:

[image]

I expected to see the article list items colored in red, but this is not the case.
What am I missing - how to make this work?
Thank you!

Comment: I found one way to do this, not sure it is the best one though: https://nextjs.org/blog/styling-next-with-styled-jsx#one-off-global-selectors

Comment: You could use the `:global()` selector as you mentioned, or you can move the contents of `articleJsx` directly to the component's JSX.